# I want to open link from server in default app of mobile from flutter app

Tags: flutter

I'm using url_launcher library of flutter to open .mp3 file from server in flutter mobile app. But that link opens in browser, I want it to open in Mobile's default music player.
Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not directly play music file from URL,
As when you use `url_launcher` plugin it redirectes user to browser and open file,
You can use [assets_audio_player](https://pub.dev/packages/assets_audio_player) plugin to play audio file from URL.